# jQuery .toggle() and Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.toggle()` on a `button` element:

```
$("header button").click(function(event){
    $(".site-nav-wrapper").toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This works great. The problem is if the `button` is toggled to `display:none` and then I change the device orientation, triggering my desktop media query, despite the fact I re-force `display:block;` on the desktop media query, the `button` remains toggled to `display:none`:

(Sass):

```
.site-nav-wrapper{

            //Mobile First
            display:none;

            @include breakpoint($breakpoint-lg) {
                display:block;
            }
}
```

Is there a way to reset whatever the `toggle()` function is storing?

Comment: You can try removing the element's `style` attribute: `$("header button").removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toggle` uses inline styling, which overrides whatever you're doing in your stylesheet.

To get the desired result, you should use a special `hidden` class to hide the element, and use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead.

**SASS:**

```css
.site-nav-wrapper.hidden {

    display: none;

    @include breakpoint($breakpoint-lg) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("header button").click(function(event){
    $(".site-nav-wrapper").toggleClass('hidden');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks. This is the only solution that works for replacing slidetoggle and fadetoggle with using CSS animation.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly `toggle` sets the `display` property to `none` on the element's `style` attribute.  If you want to *force* the button to display in the "desktop" orientation then you'll need to include an `!important` declaration in your desktop breakpoint.

Alternately, you can listen for [`onorientationchanged`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html) and switch to the desktop version of the site then (un-toggling / activating everything that needs to be activated).

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid the toggle so there's no issues with the media queries.

```
$("header button").click(function(event){
    $(".site-nav-wrapper:visible").hide();
    $(".site-nav-wrapper:hidden").show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```